# wordpress contact form not sending email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form

I am developing a contact form on my wordpress blog on a windows server(not for my choice...).

I am having trouble to make wordpress send email.
I've been using most popular plugin for this (Such as Grunion Contact form and Contact 7), all working on my preview machine(Linux based).

Anybody knows about this issue? is it a php server configuration?

Comment: I think you'll have to use SMTP if you're using WP and CF7 on Windows servers.  All Server issue ;)

Comment: Do you know how to setup SMTP?

Comment: Check this link also http://angstrey.com/index.php/2009/07/20/contact-form-7s-failed-to-send-your-message-error/

Comment: Ok this artcle is great...but problem is that i do not get the message error in red frame....i got message that the email has been sent in green border....

Comment: ..very sorry..was off during weekend...if ur problem yet not resolved ..let me know them :)

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP issue has become a lot more common for sure. As another option to CF7 with Postman, you could use Formstack instead. Formstack gets around the SMTP issue perfectly, without the need for additional plugins.

All forms can have periodic sending issues, which can be super annoying. Formstack has been awesome, but we did encounter a recent issue, which related to a client's mailbox, so it could be worth a read to help you. The form wouldn't send (although it did store all the submissions) and this was triggered by a periodically full mailbox. The result was the client's email got blacklisted.

Check out our trouble shooting article about [Formstack Emails Not Sending](http://www.mediaheroesbrisbane.com.au/insights/formstack-issues-notification-emails-not-sending/). Even though it's Formstack specific, I have a feeling this could affect other forms too, so it could come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

A great plugin that helps you diagnose these issues and even give your CF7 plugin another mail engine to use is Postman SMTP: https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/. I use it in conjunction with Contact Form 7 with great results. It will create a php mail engine for you if you need one/haven't built one already.